# Hardware, architecture needed to be able to send bit-level messages on a CAN bus

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, gpio, can, bit-bang

I have a can bus with nodes and I need to be able to send low-level messages on this network, i.e. messages defined by ones and zeros and I also need such fine grained control so as to be able to change the nominal bit time on an individual bit-level. For example, defining a correct can message "....10110101001...." and changing how many (sub?)microseconds the bit with index n is displayed on the network. I need to be able to perform the bit stuffing and crc all on my own etc.

I understand that this is hard, not advisable and that there are high-level adapters, interfaces and e.g. Python libraries to send correctly defined messages where you can specify the arbitration id, data on byte level but again, I need bit level control.

What is the easiest way to do this? What hardware is required? So far my thinking is: defining correct messages on a computer and sending the bitstring to either a microcontroller or a suitable function generator via usb. On the microcontroller I will use the GPIO pins for PWM (? unsure about the terminology here or if it's the right way), i.e. turn them on and off according to the bitstring message and a delay function with a delay according to the nominal bit times. How small, accurate delay can be achieved on different microcontrollers, is it possible to go below 1 microsecond? I am assuming I need something after this to convert the output from the microcontroller to voltage levels according to CAN. In general, what is this component called or how is this last step achieved?

Any hints, tips, clarifications or guidelines are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you're asking for transceiver circuitry to allow differential signalling that supports dominant and recessive states?

Comment: "I need something after this to convert the output from the microcontroller to voltage levels according to CAN. In general, what is this component called"  That would be a PHY.  In addition to voltage level translation, it detects a stuck state and disconnects, allowing the rest of the bus to resume operation.  But it *doesn't* control bit timing, detection of collisions, etc.

Comment: Note that a USART+DMA module configured for SPI is really good for output and capture of arbitrary digital patterns... unlike UART mode, you aren't forced to have some stop and start bits in a particular state, you can program the level of every single interval in your pattern, and send the pattern out at a programmable baud rate.  Expect maximum rates in the range of 25-50 MHz.

Comment: What you don't use is a software delay function.

Comment: Would go with a FPGA for this. USB->FPGA->CAN Transreceiver. Software on PC generates "the test-patterns required ([numberOfPoints,List<bitValue,time>])" and stores it to the FPGA RAM. Then user "triggers the frame" via mouse-click, FPGA generates bit-pattern with minimum set bit-time (e.g nominal bit time for your bus / 128= timer granularity... Gives you 0<->2*nominal bittime). Some controll registers, some UX-design and four hardware revisions later youll be done. 

Please outline why you need such low-level controll? What is oyur intention?

Comment: The bus driver can be as simple as any RS485 driver. -- Use DE to output your transmitted bit levels and wire TX to GND. This way you have the correct recessive and dominant states. Use "high" as "idle" state. -- Wire RE to "always enabled" to be able to watch the bus.